# Selector outside of style sheet with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, selector

I'm looking for a way to make some CSS only apply if an input outside the style sheet has a certain value.

In the example below I only want to run the CSS if the input value below is "4625585".

It is from a form where the submit button sends the input value (among other things).

Is that possible at all when I only have access to CSS and not the HTML code of the form.

Kindly, Rasmus

-

*Here is the CSS*

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wForm {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }      
</style>

<input value="4625585">
```

-

Here is the HTML:

```html
<form>
    <div id="tfa_6" class="wForm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>

    <input value="4626442">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with just css + html.. also indent your code - makes it easier to read :) industry standard is 4 spaces :) also, you don't need `type` because html5 is a thing now :)

Comment: Which input are you trying to match, the one in the first snippet, or the one in the second?

Comment: @JacquesMarais The first. I only have access to CSS.

Comment: What does "outside of style sheet" even mean? HTML and CSS are two completely different languages - there's no way an HTML element could be inside a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was commented on and answered in a deleted threat. This short answer is "no, it can't be done".

Answer (score 1):

You can only apply CSS to a sibling that follows the element that's validated. Therefore I moved the `input` element with `value 4625585` to the top in the form.

If you don't have access to the HTML, you will need javascript.

```css
input[value="4625585"] ~ .wForm {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <input value="4625585">
  
  <div id="tfa_6" class="wForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>

</form>
```